# Sort Documents Without Existing Field to End of Results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents, few documents only have `bids` fields.

**Collection:**

```
   { 
        "_id" : "PqwSsLb2jsqTycMWR", 
        "name" : "aaa", 
        "bids" : [
            {
                "amount" : NumberInt(450)
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "93EDoQfeYEFk8pyzX", 
        "name" : "bbb"
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "j5wkK5Eagnwuo8Jym", 
        "name" : "ccc", 
        "bids" : [
            {
                "amount" : NumberInt(520)
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "eLaTyM5h5kqA97WQQ", 
        "name" : "ddd"
    }
```

If I sort with `bids.amount : 1` am getting below results

**Result:**

```
   { 
       "_id" : "93EDoQfeYEFk8pyzX", 
       "name" : "bbb"
   }
   { 
       "_id" : "eLaTyM5h5kqA97WQQ", 
       "name" : "ddd"
   }
   { 
        "_id" : "PqwSsLb2jsqTycMWR", 
        "name" : "aaa", 
        "bids" : [
            {
                "amount" : NumberInt(450)
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "j5wkK5Eagnwuo8Jym", 
        "name" : "ccc", 
        "bids" : [
            {
                "amount" : NumberInt(520)
            }
        ]
    }
```

But I want to re arrange the order where `bid.amount` should comes at top.

**Expected result:**

```
   { 
        "_id" : "PqwSsLb2jsqTycMWR", 
        "name" : "aaa", 
        "bids" : [
            {
                "amount" : NumberInt(450)
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "j5wkK5Eagnwuo8Jym", 
        "name" : "ccc", 
        "bids" : [
            {
                "amount" : NumberInt(520)
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "93EDoQfeYEFk8pyzX", 
        "name" : "bbb"
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "eLaTyM5h5kqA97WQQ", 
        "name" : "ddd"
    }
```

Whats the query to get expected result?

Answer (score 8):

Since you are specifiying a field that does not exist in all documents in your `.sort()` then where it is not present the value is considered `null`, which is of course a lower order and therefore a higher precedence in the sorted result than any other value.

The only way to can alter that response is to essentially "project" a higher value from which to sort on than the other expected value range so that those results fall to the end of other results. Such "weighted" queries with a projected value require the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method instead:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "bids": 1,
        "sortfield": { "$ifNull": [ "$bids", 999999 ] }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "sortfield": 1 } }
])
```

This uses the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) aggregation pipline stages to get the result in the desired order. First with the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operation to decide what to place in the "sortfield" property of the projected document depending on what data is present and then using that value within the `$sort` aggregation pipeline stage.

You can also integrate normal query operations with a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage at the start of the pipeline, which would be recommended to reduce the documents needed to be processed in the `$project` stage.

With documents not containing the required field the value of "sortfield" will then be higher than expected values and those documents will appear at the end rather than at the start.

Comment: Just don't forget to revert modified filed after sort completed