# MongoDB Aggregation Sort Differently Depending on Projection

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework, projection

I have found an odd sorting behavior from MongoDB as I completed the MongDB Course M121.

You can test out the collection in this cluster with

```
mongo mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017/aggregations?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl -u m121 -p aggregations --norc
```

When I run the following the aggregate sort:

```
var favorites = [
  "Sandra Bullock",
  "Tom Hanks",
  "Julia Roberts",
  "Kevin Spacey",
  "George Clooney"]

db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "tomatoes.viewer.rating": { $gte: 3 },
      countries: "USA",
      cast: {
        $in: favorites
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      title: 1,
      "tomatoes.viewer.rating": 1,
      num_favs: {
        $size: {
          $setIntersection: [
            "$cast",
            favorites
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { num_favs: -1, "tomatoes.viewer.rating": -1, title: -1 }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  }
])
```

I'll get the following result:

```
{ "title" : "Gravity", "tomatoes" : { "viewer" : { "rating" : 4 } }, "num_favs" : 2 }
{ "title" : "A Time to Kill", "tomatoes" : { "viewer" : { "rating" : 3.6 } }, "num_favs" : 2 }
{ "title" : "Extremely Loud & Incredibly Close", "tomatoes" : { "viewer" : { "rating" : 3.5 } }, "num_favs" : 2 }
{ "title" : "Charlie Wilson's War", "tomatoes" : { "viewer" : { "rating" : 3.5 } }, "num_favs" : 2 }
{ "title" : "The Men Who Stare at Goats", "tomatoes" : { "viewer" : { "rating" : 3 } }, "num_favs" : 2 }
```

But if I change the projection slightly, from:

```
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      title: 1,
      "tomatoes.viewer.rating": 1,
```

To

```
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      title: 1,
      rating: "$tomatoes.viewer.rating",
```

or if I rid of the rating all together:

```
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      title: 1,
```

The resulting sort would also change:

```
{ "title" : "The Men Who Stare at Goats", "rating" : 3, "num_favs" : 2 }
{ "title" : "Gravity", "rating" : 4, "num_favs" : 2 }
{ "title" : "Extremely Loud & Incredibly Close", "rating" : 3.5, "num_favs" : 2 }
{ "title" : "Charlie Wilson's War", "rating" : 3.5, "num_favs" : 2 }
{ "title" : "A Time to Kill", "rating" : 3.6, "num_favs" : 2 }
```

Notice how the movie Gravity is no longer the top result.

Would anyone understand why sorting would change based on the projection? I was not expecting the projection to cause any changes to the sorting.

Comment: You are sorting by non-existing field `"tomatoes.viewer.rating": -1` after you have changed `$project` fields

Comment: Take a look [Sort Documents Without Existing Field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276149/3710490)

Comment: Oh, I see. So by specifying the non-existing field (because the projection did not include the field), `sort()` simply attempted to sort by `null`. Did I have a correct understanding?

Comment: You are right, thats the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the projection did not include the `tomatoes.viewer.rating`, the `sort()` would assume it is `null` and then sort the field based on `null` instead of actual values.

To solve, simply include the field in the projection to avoid this behavior.