# Mongodb find query's projected fields are not being used by sort

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb, my version is 5.0.15. I was having doubt on the projected fields in the `find` query. I have the following query

```js
db.movies.find({}, {title:1, rating:"$imdb.rating"}).sort({rating:1})
```

The above query doesn't sort using the `rating` field. If I replace `rating` with `imdb.rating` then it works fine. Can someone explain why is it so?

Like even if I use fields which are not projected but in the original document, the command sorts using them as well. *I know I can achieve the same using aggregate but I want to know the reason why this not works.* Any link to documentation would be appreciated.

Output -

Using `db.movies.find({}, {title:1, rating: "$imdb.rating"}).sort({"rating":1})`
[image]

Using `db.movies.find({}, {title:1, rating: "$imdb.rating"}).sort({"imdb.rating":1})`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs on [sort](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#interaction-with-projection) mention that when **Interaction with Projection**

> When a set of results are both sorted and projected, the MongoDB query
> engine will always apply the sorting **first**.

When a MongoDB query is sorted and projected, the sorting is always applied first, before the projection. This means that the sort order is based on the original field, before it's projected.
So in your original document there is no field called `rating`. That is why you need to pass the field `imdb.rating` in your sort. Since `rating` is not existing in original document it will be considered as `null` in the sort (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276149/13583510))

Comment: Ok, so except aggregation all other queries that have both projection and sorting will apply sorting first?

Comment: @Dhruv you are correct. also in aggregation you can put sort to the top of the pipeline to sort first